# Displaying data in JTable while reading the data from the text file

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

I'm trying to display the column data from separate file and row data from another but it's output is not in normal for row file below attached is the image file for output and both the text file:

```
private void orbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) orderitemtable.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    String filename = "ORDERITEMFILE.txt";
    String idnamefile = "odcofile.txt";
    File file1 = new File(idnamefile);
    File file = new File(filename);
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        //to make the columns name so to get the first line of code
        //set columnsname to the jtable Model
        String firstLine = br.readLine().trim();
        String[] columnsName = firstLine.split("/");
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);
        //get lines from txt files
        Object[] tablelines = br1.lines().toArray();
        //Extracting the data from lines
        //set data to jtable Model
        for (int i = 0; i < tablelines.length; i++) {
            String line = tablelines[i].toString().trim();
            String[] dataRow = line.split(",");
            model.addRow(dataRow);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(productpage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The problem is its displaying the column's until product type after that it changes to new row and display the rest of content over there:

[image]

This is [the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni4dI.png) for row it read's properly from the txt file the only problem is when it display in `JTable` it read's in separate row for the last two quantities.

This is [the text file for column which.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntsHP.png)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data as `String` objects in the MCVE / SSCCE. More generally: 1) See also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831) 2) Don't include images of text content, include the text as **text.** 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: Based on my minor experimentation, there doesn't seem to be any particular issue. This suggests that the issue is with the input file itself

Comment: @MadProgrammer but the file i checked it so many times it does sperated by the , and it contains 6 column data.

Comment: Based on my simple tests, the code used to read the files seems to be correct, I surmise that the input contains a “return” character somewhere in the middle of the line, which is causing the BufferedReader to split it prematurely. NotePad won’t show this, it requires a “newline” AND “return” before it splits the line

Answer (score 1):

First off, you really don't need a single file to hold Column Names. You can apply the Column Names as the very first line of your **ORDERITEMFILE.txt** file, very much like a **CSV** file would be laid out. Generally the first line of a CSV file would be a delimited string of the Column Names and it's there to be specifically used as such.

If you insist on utilizing two files then may I suggest you deal with the Column Names file first and be rid of it so that it doesn't clutter things up within your event code. Perhaps do this in a separate method:

```
private String[] getColumnNames(String filePath) {
    String[] columns = {};
    //Try with Resources (auto closes the reader)
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        String line;
        // Assumes there is only one line in file.
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Ignore blank lines (if any) leading to the line we want.
            if (!line.equals("")) { break; }
        }
        if (line != null && !line.equals("")) {
           columns = line.split("/");
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("Column Names File Not Found!");
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("IO Exception Encounterd!\n" + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return columns;
}
```

Holding the thought of keeping things organized to some degree we now can have another method to set the new Column Names to JTable:

```
private void setTableColumns(JTable table, String[] columnsName) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);
}
```

And still holding the organizational thought we have yet another method to fill the JTable with file data:

```
private int fillTableFromFile(JTable table, String filePath) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int recordCount = 0;
    //Try with Resources (auto closes the reader)
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        // Clear current table rows
        while (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                model.removeRow(i);
            }
        }
        String dataLine;
        Object[] dataArray;
        // read in the data and add to table.
        while ((dataLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Ignore blank lines (if any).
            if (dataLine.equals("")) { continue; }
            //Split the comma delimited data line into a Object Array
            dataArray = dataLine.split(",");
            model.addRow(dataArray);
            recordCount++;
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("Data File Not Found!");
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("IO Exception Encounterd!\n" + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return recordCount; // The number of records added to table from file.
}
```

With the above methods in place you can now have some 'easy to follow' (and controllable) code within your JButton Action Performed event. By controllable, I mean for example, you can determine what is to happen if (for whatever reason) the **coloumnsName** String Array is empty or null (not handled here):

```
private void orbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String filename="ORDERITEMFILE.txt";
    String idnamefile="odcofile.txt";
    String[] columnsName = getColumnNames(idnamefile);
    setTableColumns(orderitemtable, columnsName);
    int numOfRecords = fillTableFromFile(orderitemtable, filename);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(orderitemtable, "There were " + numOfRecords + 
                        " Records Added to Table.", "Records Added", 
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

When run and the Order Button is selected the table columns names will be placed, the table will be filled with file data, and a Message Box will appear indicating how many file records were added to table.

Comment: still the same thing and its displaying there were 2 rows added

Comment: @cheekybones - Not sure what the problem may be in that case. I can't seem to simulate the issue. I would suggest you try this with a new JTable and see what happens then (perhaps in a new test project).